# Python: Elementwise comparison of same shaped arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have n matrices of the same size and want to see how many cells are equal to each other across all matrices.  Code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.array([[5,6,7], [4,2,6], [7, 8, 9]])
c = np.array([2,3,4],[4,5,6],[1,2,5])

#Intuition is below but is wrong
a == b == c
```

How do I get Python to return a value of 2 (cells 2,1 and 2,3 match in all 3 matrices) or an array of [[False, False, False], [True, False, True], [False, False, False]]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
(a == b) & (b==c)

[[False False False]
 [ True False  True]
 [False False False]]
```

For `n` items in, say, a list like `x=[a, b, c, a, b, c]`, one could do:

```
r = x[0] == x[1]
for temp in x[2:]:
    r &= x[0]==temp
```

The result in now in `r`.

If the structure is already in a 3D numpy array, one could also use:

```
np.amax(x,axis=2)==np.amin(x,axis=2)
```

The idea for the above line is that although it would be ideal to have an `equal` function with an `axis` argument, there isn't one so this line notes that if `amin==amax` along the axis, then all elements are equal.

---

If the different arrays to be compared aren't already in a 3D numpy array (or won't be in the future), looping the list is a fast and easy approach.  Although I generally agree with avoiding Python loops for Numpy arrays, this seems like a case where it's easier and faster (see below) to use a Python loop since the loop is only along a single axis and it's easy to accumulate the comparisons in place.  Here's a timing test:

```
def f0(x):
    r = x[0] == x[1]
    for y in x[2:]:
        r &= x[0]==y

def f1(x):  # from @Divakar
    r = ~np.any(np.diff(np.dstack(x),axis=2),axis=2)

def f2(x):
    x = np.dstack(x)
    r = np.amax(x,axis=2)==np.amin(x,axis=2)

# speed test
for n, size, reps in ((1000, 3, 1000), (10, 1000, 100)):
    x = [np.ones((size, size)) for i in range(n)]
    print n, size, reps
    print "f0: ",
    print timeit("f0(x)", "from __main__ import x, f0, f1", number=reps)
    print "f1: ",
    print timeit("f1(x)", "from __main__ import x, f0, f1", number=reps)
    print

1000 3 1000
f0:  1.14673900604  # loop
f1:  3.93413209915  # diff
f2:  3.93126702309  # min max

10 1000 100
f0:  2.42633581161  # loop
f1:  27.1066679955  # diff
f2:  25.9518558979  # min max
```

If arrays are already in a single 3D numpy array (eg, from using `x = np.dstack(x)` in the above) then modifying the above function defs appropriately and with the addition of the `min==max` approach gives:

```
def g0(x):
    r = x[:,:,0] == x[:,:,1]
    for iy in range(x[:,:,2:].shape[2]):
        r &= x[:,:,0]==x[:,:,iy]

def g1(x):   # from @Divakar
    r = ~np.any(np.diff(x,axis=2),axis=2)

def g2(x):
    r = np.amax(x,axis=2)==np.amin(x,axis=2)
```

which yields:

```
1000 3 1000
g0:  3.9761030674      # loop
g1:  0.0599548816681   # diff
g2:  0.0313589572906   # min max

10 1000 100
g0:  10.7617051601     # loop
g1:  10.881870985      # diff
g2:  9.66712999344     # min max
```

Note also that for a list of large arrays `f0 = 2.4` and for a pre-built array `g0, g1, g2 ~= 10.`, so that if the input arrays are large, than fastest approach by about 4x is to store them separately in a list. I find this a bit surprising and guess that this might be due to cache swapping (or bad code?), but I'm not sure anyone really cares so I'll stop this here.

Comment: Is there a generalized answer?  If I have more than 3 matrices, the combinations and steps necessary to arrive at an answer will explode.

Comment: @user1842834: I should also note that the "combinations" don't "explode".  There are no combinations and explosions and this is just O(n). Think of it as a single element array, say, the number `5`.  Then you have a list of numbers and you go along the list asking whether each of the elements is equal to `5`.  It's just that but for a matrix.  There's no need to compare every element to every other.

Answer (score 4):

Concatenate along the third axis with [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and perfom differentiation with [`np.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), so that the identical ones would show up as zeros. Then, check for cases where all are zeros with [`~np.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html). Thus, you would have a one-liner solution like so -

```
~np.any(np.diff(np.dstack((a,b,c)),axis=2),axis=2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [39]: a
Out[39]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [40]: b
Out[40]: 
array([[5, 6, 7],
       [4, 2, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [41]: c
Out[41]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 5]])

In [42]: ~np.any(np.diff(np.dstack((a,b,c)),axis=2),axis=2)
Out[42]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
z1 = a == b
z2 = a == c
z  = np.logical_and(z1,z2)
print "count:", np.sum(z)
```

You can do this in a single statement:

```
count = np.sum( np.logical_and(a == b, a == c) )
```